# Tomcat can't find a class freemarker.template.TemplateException

Tags: java, tomcat, exception, freemarker, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to use the Freemarker template engine in my web app. But for some reason TomCat doesn't find class *freemarker.template.TemplateException* and I can not understand where is a problem because I try to generate html string in main function using freemarker and it works!

StackTrace of the Exception:

```
11-Apr-2018 17:46:00.353 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [ProfileServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root causejava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: freemarker.template.TemplateException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
at servlets.ProfileServlet.doGet(ProfileServlet.java:26)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved it. Just needed to add freemarker.jar package to WEB-INF/lib directory of the project. But I still do not understand why loading with maven did not work.

**UPD:** Sometimes Tomcat works strange with packages loaded with maven. For example if add dependency for mysql-connector of new version at the moment (8.0.11) Tomcat will not find *jdbc.Driver* while connecting. So this package should be added to "$CATALINA_HOME/lib" directory manually.

Comment: I guess you have ran your main method (mentioned in the question) from your IDE. Or at least not from under Tomcat. Servlet containers have their own ways of loading classes...

Comment: Yes, I did it from IDE and understand that classes load in different way to Tomcat, but other dependencies worked correctly.